# Predicting the difference between two groups in R

Tags: r, regression, self-study

I'm working on practice exercises with R. From the data, I now have to determine the difference in predicted male compared to female spending while keeping all other predictors constant.

I replaced the sex `0,1` with `male, female`:

```
> spending$sex=factor(spending$sex)
> levels(spending$sex)=c("male", "female")
> tail(spending)
    sex status income verbal gamble
42 male     61  15.00      9   69.7
43 male     75   3.00      8   13.3
44 male     66   3.25      9    0.6
45 male     62   4.94      6   38.0
46 male     71   1.50      7   14.4
47 male     71   2.50      9   19.2
> summary(spending)
     sex         status          income           verbal     
 male  :28   Min.   :18.00   Min.   : 0.600   Min.   : 1.00  
 female:19   1st Qu.:28.00   1st Qu.: 2.000   1st Qu.: 6.00  
             Median :43.00   Median : 3.250   Median : 7.00  
             Mean   :45.23   Mean   : 4.642   Mean   : 6.66  
             3rd Qu.:61.50   3rd Qu.: 6.210   3rd Qu.: 8.00  
             Max.   :75.00   Max.   :15.000   Max.   :10.00  
     gamble     
 Min.   :  0.0  
 1st Qu.:  1.1  
 Median :  6.0  
 Mean   : 19.3  
 3rd Qu.: 19.4  
 Max.   :156.0
```

Now, this is where I got stumped, how do I set this up with constants and only use the `sex` variable?

Comment: Related to your question [Predicting response for two groups in multiple regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/36019/930) (under a different account). Could you please indicate to one of the moderators (by flagging your post here) which account you want to keep and [register](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq#login)?

Comment: the other question can be removed..Chrissy was working on the same problem and posted same data.

Answer (score 2):

You've got one big problem in your data as posted: there's no "spending" column, so you don't have a response. Once you get that, just run a linear model with sex as your only predictor.

```
 yourModel <- lm(spending ~ sex, data = spending)
 summary(yourModel)
```

The base level (intercept only) corresponds to your factor's 0-level, in this case male. The difference between the levels is sex coefficient in the model output.

When you have more than 2 levels, the output is explicit. For example, using the built-in dataset `mtcars`

```
head(mtcars)
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl)
mylm <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)

> levels(mtcars$cyl)
[1] "4" "6" "8"

> summary(mylm)

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.2636 -1.8357  0.0286  1.3893  7.2364 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  26.6636     0.9718  27.437  < 2e-16 ***
cyl6         -6.9208     1.5583  -4.441 0.000119 ***
cyl8        -11.5636     1.2986  -8.905 8.57e-10 ***
---
```

Here the factor levels are called out, with the 0-level (4-cylinder) corresponding the the intercept. As in your example, when there are no other predictors, this is as simple as taking the means for each factor level. The 4-cyl mean is 26.66, same as the intercept, and then adding -6.9 we get the 6-cyl mean, and adding -11.56 (to the original 26.66) we get the 8-cyl mean of 15.1.

```
> with(mtcars, tapply(mpg, cyl, mean)) ## just calculates mean mpg at each level of cyl
       4        6        8 
26.66364 19.74286 15.10000
```

Comment: sorry, i had two data sets on board..gamble is the spending column....I copied the wrong text. I did as you suggested,

Comment: I hit enter to quickly
Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-29.775 -18.325  -3.766   6.334 126.225 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   29.775      5.498   5.415 2.28e-06 ***
sex          -25.909      8.648  -2.996  0.00444 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 29.09 on 45 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.1663, Adjusted R-squared: 0.1478 
F-statistic: 8.977 on 1 and 45 DF,  p-value: 0.004437 
But how do i predict male compared to female from this lm?

Comment: This means that females spends on average 25.909 less than males

Comment: But, how is it females spend less and not vice-versa?

Comment: Despite your recoding of sex as a factor, you could still think of it as being 0 or 1. Since you put "male" as first, that's the "0", the baseline. The sex coefficient with value -25.909 is in effect only for females. Since you have no other predictors, you should also be able to enter in `with(spending, tapply(gamble, sex, mean))` and see that 25.909 is simply the difference between the spending means for males and females.

Comment: :) trust data, but not your suggestions. By default R treats first level (male) as 0 and the second (female) as 1. Note, that this is gamble spending. Males are much more risky gamblers than females.

Comment: thanks for the clarification and the other example help me understand both problems. Thanks

Comment: so if i use all the predictors in the linear model, Residual standard error: 22.69 on 42 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.5267, Adjusted R-squared: 0.4816 
F-statistic: 11.69 on 4 and 42 DF,  p-value: 1.815e-06 
The r2 means that 53% of the variation can be explained by these predictors.

Comment: Yes, though if you compare models adjusted R-squared would be better to use, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2870766/903061)

Comment: Continuing with the spending model, a correlation of the residuals with income will be calculated as cor(resid(mdl),(income))
[1] -7.242382e-17

Comment: For practice, I used the formula > signif(summary(fit)$r.squared, digits=3)
[1] 0.506 and I get a different R square from my data above. Please clarify why they are different

Comment: Long discussions in comments generally aren't productive. You might want to ask a new question.